# How to connect to DataSources dynamically at runtime?

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jndi

This is the situation - I have JBOSS EAP 6.4 setup as my application server and have defined some JNDI data sources in it. The name and number of the data sources can vary across environments. I need to write a webservice which takes JNDI data source and query as input. It should connect to the respective data source and execute the query.

So the JNDI data source name should not be hardcoded in the application and it should be taken as input at runtime.

I cannot use the below spring config to define the datasource since this would make it hardcoded -

```
<bean id="dbDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/myDS2"/>
</bean>
```

I would like to do something like:

```
<bean id="dbDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="${dataSourceInput}"/>
</bean>
```

where `${dataSourceInput}` is the input for the webservice.

Please, let me know how to achieve it.

Update --

I do not want the datasource name to be passed in as a JVM argument or through a parameter file. The datasource name has to be passed as an input to the webservice. The above code snippet is probably not the right way to do it. Probably this is not possible through spring config file.

Please, let me know if there is any other way to achieve the same.

Comment: You can check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507522/dynamically-change-spring-data-source).  Define one main DS and multiple DS's and check which to get invoked dynamically. Your `${dataSourceInput}` would be just a  String.

Comment: I went through the link. It still needs all the data sources to be defined in  the spring config file. And then dynamically decide which among them needs to be used. Here my requirement is different. I do not know the number/names of the datasources defined at the application server level. So cannot define all of them in the spring config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After search for a while I found the answer I was looking for.

I can create the datasource form the JNDI name which is taken as input to the webservice as below.

```
dataSourceInput = <input from the webservice>
ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(dataSourceInput);
```

Reference - http://www.journaldev.com/2513/tomcat-datasource-jndi-example-java

Answer (score 0):

You would populate either from a properties file or a -D parameter to the JVM -

So in the case of JVM argument -

```
-DdataSourceInput=java:jboss/datasources/myDS2
```

There are other ways of achieving similar but this is simplest

If you are using xml then the properties file is imported by -

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/myproperties.properties" />
```

With the properties containing -

```
dataSourceInput=java:jboss/datasources/myDS2
```

Comment: the JNDI data source name should be passed as an input to the webservice and not as JVM argument.

Comment: maybe the way i am configuring in spring is wrong. I would probably have to configure it in code rather than spring config file

Comment: Updated with the approach i use

Comment: Its mandatory that the JNDI name is passed as input to the webservice and not through the properties file.

Comment: Spring htroughs an exception if it cannot find the property so the property is mandatory

Comment: is it possible to achieve the same without using spring then?

Comment: yes - numerous ways including other DI frameworks, or Java CDI

Comment: can you point me to some examples or provide some code snippets for the same?