# Check for mysql database existance then edit hibernate configuration file to new connection

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

When I change current database to another ip address.

like :From `<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.2.14:3306/pms"/>`
To `<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.2.16:3306/pms"/>`

How can I edit it in runtime.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.2.14:3306/pms"/>
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>
```

Thanks in advance.

I am changing value of url From UI.

I am passing class in following function.

```
public void recursiveWire(Object root) throws Exception {
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/pms/controller/dispatcher-servlet.xml");

        context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(root);
        context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().initializeBean(root, null);

        for (Field field : root.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(FXML.class) && !Node.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
                // <== assume if not a Node, must be a controller
                recursiveWire(field.get(root));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answer may answer to your question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507522/dynamically-change-spring-data-source

Comment: Thanks for link but it's not solution of my problem.

Comment: create your Datasource in your code.

Comment: I am new in this can you describe "How to create Datasource in code".
Thanks.. @ Scary Wombat

Comment: From where are you changing the value of url? In DAO class or fetching the url entered in some UI.

Comment: I am changing value of url From UI.

Comment: I am checking first for database existance.If it is not exist then prompt inputbox for mysql database authentication details.