# How to let a user select a database at runtime for Spring-data-JPA

Tags: java, sqlite, spring-data-jpa

I'm writing a JavaFX application that needs to talk to a SQLite database, stored as a .db file, that the user has selected from their filesystem. This can be any .db file that I do not know of at build time.

I'd like to use Spring/JPA2, but as far as I know it only allows for using databases configured at build-time. Is what I want possible in Spring/JPA2, and if so, how would I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Is it the same as this?

[implement dynamically datasource in spring data jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48825734/implement-dynamically-datasource-in-spring-data-jpa)

Tried searching for spring boot microservice and webclient if you want other workarounds.

Comment: Those still use preconfigured datatbases, but I could override DataSource. The problem will still be how to start the app without a DataSource and how to switch to the new DataSource once the user opens one.

Comment: how about this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074631/spring-boot-application-without-a-datasource). You may check this one also [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-data-source-programmatic)